# PHP Array inventory editing

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a system where inventory is stored in a single database table. I need help to find the best way to add/remove items from this.

It is stored as follows;

3:1|8:2|5:3|4:4

the first number represents quantity and the second number is the item ID. The Pipe | splits these items.

So 3:1 = quantity 3 of item 1.

I am trying to use PHP to look at this string, find if the item is there. If it is add to or remove from it. OR if the item isn't there then create it.

I know I would have to use an array to achieve this but I'm a little lost at how this would be done, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this but why do you store it this way?

Comment: It's part of an existing system which I'm adding on to, I honestly wouldn't have done it this way.

Comment: ok, what did you try?

Comment: I'm at a loss on where to go with it. I load it from the database but I'm not familiar enough with arrays and get a little confused as to what is happening. I tried to implode/explode but not 100% on which one would be needed with this. My understanding is that I would have to look for :(id) but then I can't load the quantity or add it back into the array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a small class that holds an item -> quantity map (stored as an array) that is created from that string, and builds the string back when requested.

This makes use of:

- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string parts,
- [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) combined with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to join them back.

Code:

```
class DataStructure
{
  private $data = [];

  public function __construct(string $data)
  {
    foreach (explode('|', $data) as $item_quantity) {
      list($quantity, $item) = explode(':', $item_quantity);
      $this->data[$item] = (int)$quantity;
    }
  }

  public function getItemQuantity(int $item): ?int
  {
    return $this->data[$item] ?? null;
  }

  public function setItemQuantity(int $item, int $quantity)
  {
    $this->data[$item] = $quantity;
  }

  public function __toString(): string
  {
    return implode('|', array_map(function ($item) {
      return $this->data[$item] . ':' . $item;
    }, array_keys($this->data)));
  }
}
```

Note that this doesn't include error handling, for the purpose of this example.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/pqRQh**

**Demo (PHP 5.6 compatible): https://3v4l.org/tK9Q9**

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I am getting the error "PHP Fatal error:  Non-abstract method DataStructure::getItemQuantity() must contain body in (Path)" 

And

"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in"

for line 14

Comment: @EarlGrey Oh, forgot to mention this requires PHP 7.1+. Let me adjust this code for PHP5 then, give me a couple minutes.

Comment: @EarlGrey Here's the [PHP5.6 compatible version](https://3v4l.org/tK9Q9) (also added to the answer).

Comment: Thanks again! I'm trying to implement it into my script and using; https://3v4l.org/psa8F - Should this work? I'm not quite sure I'm using this correctly.

Comment: @EarlGrey `'$newTotal'` should be `$newTotal` (without the quotes around it).

Comment: I did that though anything after that code breaks :/

Comment: @EarlGrey That's not nearly accurate enough for me to help :) What error are you getting? What is happening? etc.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include log; "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getItemQuantity() on null" - Item quantity is 3, I checked the variable before it goes in.

Comment: @EarlGrey How is `$data` defined? It should be something along the line of `$data = new DataStructure('3:1|8:2|5:3|4:4')` (you can replace that hardcoded string with a value retrieved into a variable from your database).

Comment: I just realized that string was empty. I tested and got the values in, now the error is; PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getItemQuantity() on string

Comment: @EarlGrey I don't think you read my last comment. `$data` should not be the value itself, but a `DataStructure` instance. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This is where I'm at; https://3v4l.org/MGW42

Comment: Damn I feel stupid! Haha, Thank you so much for this!

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the little check icon on its left. Also, as a general advice, I would suggest reading up on [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) as these issues/questions you've had seem to imply you're lacking a bit in these topics. Good luck.

Comment: It's true that my knowledge is lacking a lot in that area. I've always coded procedurally and put off learning classes. I will need to revisit this but you have really helped my learn a lot on this which will really benefit me in taking the next steps!